# Use Same BindingSource in 2 LookUpEdit

Tags: data-binding, devexpress

Can i use the same BindingSource for two DevExpress LookUpEditand while changing the first to reflect the other one while displaying different properties of the datasource?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say yes. Did you actually try it?